# Best practice for archiving mongoid records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a Rails app, and we have a use case where we want to maintain all of the relationships between models, but archive records.  The purpose of this is to remove inactive records but have special access to them occasionally.

One approach I thought of was to see if Rails supports overriding the collection name, and perhaps move the objects from one collection to another, and when the archive collection is specified, specify the archive table.

Is there a best practice for this kind of thing with Rails / Mongoid?

Hopefully someone can help before the SO shills shut this question down.

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new field to the model called `delete_flag`, which will by default have `false` as value. For archiving, change it to `true`

```
field :delete_flag, type: Boolean, default: false
```

And write two scopes to filter out the active ones and archived ones.

```
# Scopes
scope :active, -> { where(delete_flag: false) }
scope :archived, -> { where(delete_flag: true) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your probably looking for the Mongoid::Paranoia

> Mongoid::Paranoia enables a "soft delete" of Mongoid documents. Instead of being removed from the database, paranoid docs are flagged with a deleted_at timestamp and are ignored from queries by default.

[On Github](https://github.com/simi/mongoid_paranoia)

Comment: this might be what i want, can you force query them? or must you first restore them in order to query them? nevermind, i'm reading the docs, thanks for the tip, i'll accept your answer after i do a little research.